# IE8 and lower comment doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some trouble with IE. I have set the following comment in my pages in the head section:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But IE doesn't detect that css file. Does anyone known the problem?

Thank you.
Casper

Comment: That will target IE7 and lower. `lte` stands for *Lower than or equal to*. You sould use `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're targetting <= IE7 currently.

***Preface:***

`lte` - less than, or equal to

`gte` - greater than, or equal to

***This will target <= IE8***

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

***Which is equivalent to:***

```
[if (gte IE 1) & (lte IE 8)]>
```